# Wordpress - Restrict users in by user end to certain categories at registration

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created an `wordpress` plugin for user registration. But i would like to add some taxonomy/category selection for users at the time of registration.

I don't want to purchase any paid plugin, Is there any way to do this in `wordpress` ?

Its look like multiple category selection from the user area not from the admin area. i got some option from admin assigning but i don't prefer that option ..

Comment: If you created the plugin, then you know you can just add this feature yourself too right?

Comment: @Randy , i was tried to do , but dint find any helpful post. Could you please share if you have any url's that can guide me to complete the same..